# Algorithm Backtracking: How to do recursion without storing state

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Normally in backtracking, we take a helper function which takes in an initial state and each recursive call takes care of its own computation and pass the result to the next recursion call. Theoretically, we denote this through unseen and seen variable.

For example, in permutation for a string we will use this program:

```
def permute(str)
  return str if str.length < 2 
  permute_helper(str, "")
end 

def permute_helper(unseen, seen)
  #base case
  if unseen.length <= 0
    p seen
    return
  else 
    (0..unseen.length-1).each do |i|
      buffer = unseen 
      buffer = buffer.split('')
      buffer.delete_at(i)
      buffer = buffer.join('')
      permute_helper(buffer, seen+unseen[i])
    end 
  end
end 

permute('abc')
```

Thie will print out the required results.

I was asked to do this without using two variables in a recent interview. without storing state in the seen variable. I couldn't think through the whole at that time but I would like to ask how to do backtracking without storing states ?

Comment: That's a whole lot of code for what boils down to simple substring manipulation. `unseen[i,1] = ""` will delete `1` character at position `i`. For other occasions prefer `unseen.chars` to `unseen.split('')`.

Answer (score 8):

The permutations of the string `"cd"` is `["cd", "dc"]`. If we now wish to obtain the permutations of the string `"bcd"` we simply replace each element of this array with three strings, each having `"b"` at a different position. `"cd"` becomes `"bcd"`, `"cbd"` and `"cdb"` and `"dc"` becomes  `"bdc"`,  `"dbc"` and  `"dba"`. The permutations of `"bcd"` are therefore

```
["bcd", "cbd", "cdb", "bdc", "dbc", "dba"]
```

If we now wish to obtain the permutations of `"abcd"`, we replace each element of the above six-element array with four strings, each with `"a"` in a different position. For example, `"bcd"` becomes `"abcd"`, `"bacd"`, `"bcad"` and `"bcda"`. The structure of the recursion should now be obvious.

```
def permute(str)
  case str.length
  when 0, 1
    str
  when 2
    [str, str.reverse]
  else
    first = str[0]
    sz = str.size-1
    permute(str[1..-1]).flat_map { |s| (0..sz).map { |i| s.dup.insert(i,first) } }
  end
end

permute('')
  #=> ""
permute('a')
  #=> "a"
permute('ab')
  #=> ["ab", "ba"]
permute('abc')
  #=> ["abc", "bac", "bca", "acb", "cab", "cba"]    
permute('abcd')
  #=> ["abcd", "bacd", "bcad", "bcda", "acbd", "cabd", "cbad", "cbda",
  #    "acdb", "cadb", "cdab", "cdba", "abdc", "badc", "bdac", "bdca",
  #    "adbc", "dabc", "dbac", "dbca", "adcb", "dacb", "dcab", "dcba"]
```

`str` is of course the "unseen" variable.

Comment: very nice encoding, Cary

Answer (score 2):

@CarySwoveland's answer an explanation is awesome, per usual. For those looking to permute an *array*, consider this functional approach. While this uses an auxiliary lambda `all_pos`, no extra state parameter is used to accumulate the result.

```
def permute ((x, *xs))

  all_pos = lambda do |(y,*ys)|
    if y.nil?
      [[ x ]]
    else
      [[ x, y, *ys ]] + (all_pos.call ys) .map { |rest| [ y, *rest ] }
    end
  end

  if x.nil? or xs.empty?
    [[x]]
  else
    (permute xs) .flat_map &all_pos
  end

end

permute [1,2,3,4]

# [ [1, 2, 3, 4]
# , [2, 1, 3, 4]
# , [2, 3, 1, 4]
# , [2, 3, 4, 1]
# , [1, 3, 2, 4]
# , [3, 1, 2, 4]
# , [3, 2, 1, 4]
# , [3, 2, 4, 1]
# , [1, 3, 4, 2]
# , [3, 1, 4, 2]
# , [3, 4, 1, 2]
# , [3, 4, 2, 1]
# , [1, 2, 4, 3]
# , [2, 1, 4, 3]
# , [2, 4, 1, 3]
# , [2, 4, 3, 1]
# , [1, 4, 2, 3]
# , [4, 1, 2, 3]
# , [4, 2, 1, 3]
# , [4, 2, 3, 1]
# , [1, 4, 3, 2]
# , [4, 1, 3, 2]
# , [4, 3, 1, 2]
# , [4, 3, 2, 1]
# ]
```